# How do I turn a tuple into a tuple of tuples?

Tags: python, tuples

How do I convert this:

```
(1, 315.0, 2, 30.399999618530273, 3, 1.1033999919891357, 4, 8.0)
```

into this:

```
((1, 315.0), (2, 30.399999618530273), (3, 1.1033999919891357), (4, 8.0))
```

is there a simple way to do it without looping through?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
t = (1, 315.0, 2, 30.399999618530273, 3, 1.1033999919891357, 4, 8.0)
print tuple(zip(*[iter(t)] * 2))
```

**Edit:** To make this a bit more readable, it should probably encapsulated in a function like the `grouper()` function from the `itertools` [recipes](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes):

```
def grouper(n, iterable, fillvalue=None):
    "grouper(3, 'ABCDEFG', 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)
```

Comment: It took me a while to figure out how this solution works, but +1. I like the sharing of a single iterator over `t`.

Comment: I feel like the *[]*2 is unnecessarily complicated though. I'd prefer it = iter(t), zip(it, it)

Answer (score 16):

```
>>> x = (1, 315.0, 2, 30.399999618530273, 3, 1.1033999919891357, 4, 8.0)
>>> tuple(zip(x[::2], x[1::2]))
((1, 315.0), (2, 30.399999618530273), (3, 1.1033999919891357), (4, 8.0))
```

Answer (score 4):

I would go for generator:

```
def pairs( tup ):
    t = iter(tup)
    while True: yield t.next(), t.next()

a = (1, 315.0, 2, 30.399999618530273, 3, 1.1033999919891357, 4, 8.0)
for p in pairs(a): print p
```

As it is a bit more verbose and probably faster (does not actually allocate the paired list).

**edit:**

Reading through solutions this is much shorter:

```
t = iter(a)
print zip(t, t)
```

Comment: Bear in mind this wouldn't work if you need to loop through the generated list multiple times.

Comment: True, but you can always call pairs() second time (not really valid if passing as an argument, but in many cases you don't need second iteration).